# Page Refresh Necessary for Route re-Load in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have set up a few routes (menu links labeled Home|About|What I Do|Experience) for my portfolio site like so using `BrowswerRouter`..
[image]

When I click on any of the links the components do not load on the page or at least they are not rendering properly.  In order for them to load I have to refresh the page.  I know this is not the appropriate behavior.  I am still learning the way of React Router.  I need help with understanding why this behavior is happening and resolving this issue.  Below is the import I used and the render set up I have.  I just want to reiterate that when I refresh the page once I have routed to the component I want, it renders and loads correctly.

Thank you fellow coders!

A few files for your reference and the [Git Repo](https://github.com/KevinDennyII/that_developer/tree/adding-react-router) :-)

**App.js**

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import Introduction from "./components/introduction";
import About from "./components/about";
import WhatIDo from "./components/whatido";
import Timeline from "./components/timeline";
import Footer from "./components/footer";

const App = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [summary, setSummary] = useState("");
  const [myLinks, setMyLinks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://gitconnected.com/v1/portfolio/kevindennyii")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        //setName(data.basics.name);
        setEmail(data.basics.email);
        setSummary(data.basics.summary);
        setMyLinks(data.basics.profiles);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router>
      <div id="colorlib-page" style={{ backgroundColor: "#F4F5F4" }}>
        <div
          id="container-wrap"
          style={{ marginLeft: "5rem", marginRight: "5rem" }}
        >
          <div>
            <section
              className="colorlib-experience"
              style={{
                marginTop: "0px",
                marginBottom: "0px",
                paddingBottom: "0px",
                paddingTop: "0px",
              }}
              data-section="home"
            >
              <Introduction myLinks={myLinks} email={email} />
              <nav style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                <Link to="/">Home</Link>|<Link to="/about">About</Link>|
                <Link to="/expertise">What I Do</Link>|
                <Link to="/experience">Experience</Link>
              </nav>
            </section>
            <hr className="divider gradient" contentEditable />
          </div>
          <Switch>
            {/* use the render attribute to pass props to the route with the */}
            {/* arrow function because this will update the component as opposed to */}
            {/* component={() => <Dashboard isAuthed={true} /> */}
            <Route
              path="/about"
              render={(props) => <About {...props} summary={summary} />}
            />
            <Route path="/expertise" render={() => <WhatIDo />} />
            <Route path="/experience" component={Timeline} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Couple of components

**whatido.jsx**

```
import React from "react";

const WhatIDo = () => {
  return (
    <section className="colorlib-about" data-section="whatido">
      <div className="colorlib-narrow-content">
        <div className="row">
          <div
            className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-md-pull-3 animate-box"
            data-animate-effect="fadeInLeft"
          >
            <span className="heading-meta">What I do?</span>
            <h2 className="colorlib-heading">Here are some of my expertise</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row row-pt-md">
          <div className="col-md-4 text-center animate-box">
            <div className="services color-1">
              <span className="icon">
                <i className="icon-bulb" />
              </span>
              <div className="desc">
                <h3>Web Development </h3>
                <p>
                  I have experience building websites using Content Management
                  Systems like Wordpress. I have professional experience coding
                  in JavaScript, HTML, CSS, and object-oriented languages.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-4 text-center animate-box">
            <div className="services color-3">
              <span className="icon">
                <i className="icon-phone3" />
              </span>
              <div className="desc">
                <h3>Data Structures & Algorithms</h3>
                <p>
                  As coming from the CS background, I have good grasp over
                  fundamental concepts of DSA
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-4 text-center animate-box">
            <div className="services color-5">
              <span className="icon">
                <i className="icon-data" />
              </span>
              <div className="desc">
                <h3>Dev Ops</h3>
                <p>
                  I am Amazon Web Services (AWS) certified as a Developer
                  Associate. I have 3 years of experiences in configuring and
                  managing data solution with AWS
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
export default WhatIDo;
```

**timeline.jsx**

```
import React from "react";

// TODO
const Timeline = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <section className="colorlib-experience" data-section="timeline">
        <div className="colorlib-narrow-content">
          <div className="row">
            <div
              className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-md-pull-3 animate-box"
              data-animate-effect="fadeInLeft"
            >
              <span className="heading-meta">highlights</span>
              <h2 className="colorlib-heading animate-box">Timeline</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12">
              <div className="timeline-centered">
                <article
                  className="timeline-entry animate-box"
                  data-animate-effect="fadeInLeft"
                >
                  <div className="timeline-entry-inner">
                    <div className="timeline-icon color-3">
                      <i className="icon-pen2" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="timeline-label">
                      <h2>
                        Director of Operations at{" "}
                        <a
                          href="https://www.ohhdennyservices.com"
                          style={{ color: "#2c98f0" }}
                          target="_blank"
                          rel="noopener noreferrer"
                        >
                          OhhDenny Services, LLC
                        </a>{" "}
                        <br />
                        <span>June 2015 - present</span>
                      </h2>
                      <div>
                        <p>
                          We assist smaller business, mostly concentrating on
                          HIPPA, with Cyber Security, Software & Hardware
                          Installation and Updates, and Network Configuration.
                          We also build websites using Content Management
                          Systems like WordPress and technologies such
                          JavaScript, CSS3 & HTML5.{" "}
                        </p>
                        <p>
                          Network Upgrade for Ideal Nursing Services, Inc.: For
                          this project, I hired two other professionals to
                          assist with taking Ideal Nursing from a wired network
                          to a wireless network. Measurements of the building
                          were taken to create proper network diagrams for
                          approval by Ideal Nursing. Wires were removed and
                          Wireless Access Points (WAPs) were then installed and
                          configured. All machines were upgraded and/or
                          configured to connect to the WAPs. In addition, a new
                          rack with POE ports was installed in their server room
                          for their server, multi-port hub and router. This
                          created a more efficient working space and alleviated
                          unnecessary clutter.
                        </p>
                        <div>
                          Websites:
                          <ul>
                            <li>
                              <a
                                href="https://jacobdavidproperties.com/"
                                target="_blank"
                                rel="noopener noreferrer"
                              >
                                Jacob David Properties, LLC
                              </a>{" "}
                              - Selma , TX
                            </li>
                            <li>
                              <a
                                href="https://www.diamondgrovebaptist.com"
                                target="_blank"
                                rel="noopener noreferrer"
                              >
                                Diamond Grove Baptist Church, Inc
                              </a>{" "}
                              - Franklin, VA
                            </li>
                            <li>
                              <a
                                href="https://www.oberryamezionchurch.org"
                                target="_blank"
                                rel="noopener noreferrer"
                              >
                                O'Berry A. M. E. Zion Church
                              </a>{" "}
                              - Franklin, VA
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </article>
                <article
                  className="timeline-entry animate-box"
                  data-animate-effect="fadeInTop"
                >
                  <div className="timeline-entry-inner">
                    <div className="timeline-icon color-4">
                      <i className="icon-pen2" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="timeline-label">
                      <h2>
                        Software Engineer at iHeartMedia, Inc <br />
                        <span>Feb 2019 - July 2020</span>
                      </h2>
                      <p>
                        Currently working on iHeartMedia's Music Lab team. I
                        assist in the maintaining and improving of a web
                        application that assist in helping program directors of
                        iHeartRadio stations determine how air time (spins) for
                        songs will be distributed across radio stations. I am
                        working as both a Software Engineer and Data Analytics
                        team liaison on the Music Lab team. Some of my tasks
                        include architecting solutions with NodeJS, automating
                        AWS CodeBuilds using CloudWatch events for our MySQL
                        databases, improving technical documentation, and
                        learning both our data analytics and software
                        development stack (ReactJS) for Music Lab.
                      </p>
                      <p>
                        I conducted a Proof of Concept analysis to present to VP
                        of Data Engineering & Analytics for using an aiWare
                        platform that uses GraphQL. This was an idea to help
                        iHeartMedia automate the analysis of some of its market
                        data like spots and digital impression
                      </p>
                      <p>
                        Previously apart of the Salesforce team, working with
                        the Campaign Recap application which kept track of
                        iHeartMedia's clients radio ad campaigns. I briefly
                        worked with our Kibana instance in attempt to improve
                        logging. I updated our software architecture. I also
                        performed a technical analysis with Vertione One in
                        using there development platform with GraphiQ that could
                        possible help iHeartMedia automate some of its
                        processes.
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </article>
                <article
                  className="timeline-entry animate-box"
                  data-animate-effect="fadeInLeft"
                >
                  <div className="timeline-entry-inner">
                    <div className="timeline-icon color-5">
                      <i className="icon-pen2" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="timeline-label">
                      <h2>
                        Lead Technologist at Booz Allen Hamilton, Inc <br />
                        <span>Oct 2015 - Jan 2019</span>
                      </h2>
                      <div>
                        I have written training documentation for the Air Force
                        serving as an Elastic Stack Subject Matter Expert (SME)
                        creating Elastic Stack training courses. This included
                        modules for:
                        <ul>
                          <li>The Overview of Elastic Stack</li>
                          <li>The understanding and use of Elasticsearch</li>
                          <li>The understanding and use of Logstash</li>
                          <li>
                            The understanding and use of Kibana The
                            understanding of Beats
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                        I have created learning documentation for server
                        configuration (Puppet) and YAML
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        I participated as a member of an Agile Coaching team for
                        the Air Force, practicing Scrum using Sprints. I wrote
                        guidance for development teams such as how-to-guides and
                        best practices for use of Agile methodologies.
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        I served as a member of the DoD community working as an
                        Application Lead/Senior Developer working with and
                        managing Amazing Web Services (AWS) EC2 instances
                        building a Java application that would create and
                        maintain IT disaster recovery plans.
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        I lead and participated on projects working with
                        technologies such as PostgreSQL, MongoDB, ExpressDB,
                        AngularJS and NodeJS (MEAN) web development, Java and
                        other Microsoft technologies.
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        Internally, for Booz Allen Hamilton, I have configured
                        and implemented a prototype website using Drupal with
                        Acquia cloud.
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </article>
                <article
                  className="timeline-entry animate-box"
                  data-animate-effect="fadeInLeft"
                >
                  <div className="timeline-entry-inner">
                    <div className="timeline-icon color-6">
                      <i className="icon-pen2" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="timeline-label">
                      <h2>
                        Senior Web Developer at Sevatec, Inc <br />
                        <span>Nov 2014 - Jun 2015</span>
                      </h2>
                      <p>
                        I fulfilled the role of Web Developer as a member of the
                        Implementation Team for Content Management System (CMS),
                        redesigning of the <b>US Embassy websites</b> at the IIP
                        bureau of the <b>Department of State</b>. We were part
                        of the UI/UX team with this task. We conducted wireframe
                        testing, user interviews, and analysis on the both
                        tasks.
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        As a web developer, I was responsible for the
                        development of websites and mobile applications on
                        Amazon Web Services (AWS) via WordPress, assisting with
                        technical documentation and end-user training &
                        development transition plans. I participated in weekly
                        calls with WordPress VIP and Automattic (creators and
                        founders of WordPress) to receive guidance towards
                        implementing possible solutions for the client. I also
                        created and implemented the US Embassy Travel Alert
                        Wordpress plugin which incorporates travel warnings and
                        alerts using a JSON file from travel.state.gov.
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </article>
                <article
                  className="timeline-entry animate-box"
                  data-animate-effect="fadeInLeft"
                >
                  <div className="timeline-entry-inner">
                    <div className="timeline-icon color-5">
                      <i className="icon-pen2" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="timeline-label">
                      <h2>
                        Software Developer at Buchanan & Edwards, Inc <br />
                        <span>Nov 2013 - Oct 2014</span>
                      </h2>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </article>
                <article
                  className="timeline-entry animate-box"
                  data-animate-effect="fadeInLeft"
                >
                  <div className="timeline-entry-inner">
                    <div className="timeline-icon color-3">
                      <i className="icon-pen2" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="timeline-label">
                      <h2>
                        Software Developer at Creative Information Technology,
                        Inc
                        <br />
                        <span>May 2010 - Oct 2013</span>
                      </h2>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </article>
                <article
                  className="timeline-entry animate-box"
                  data-animate-effect="fadeInLeft"
                >
                  <div className="timeline-entry-inner">
                    <div className="timeline-icon color-2">
                      <i className="icon-pen2" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="timeline-label">
                      <h2>
                        Web Developer/IT Consultant at Intepros Federal
                        Consulting, Inc
                        <br />
                        <span>Sep 2009 - Apr 2010</span>
                      </h2>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </article>
                <article
                  className="timeline-entry animate-box"
                  data-animate-effect="fadeInLeft"
                >
                  <div className="timeline-entry-inner">
                    <div className="timeline-icon color-1">
                      <i className="icon-pen2" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="timeline-label">
                      <h2>
                        IT Specialist at IBM, Inc <br />
                        <span>Aug 2007 - Sep 2009</span>
                      </h2>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </article>
                <article
                  className="timeline-entry begin animate-box"
                  data-animate-effect="fadeInBottom"
                >
                  <div className="timeline-entry-inner">
                    <div className="timeline-icon color-none" />
                  </div>
                </article>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Timeline;
```

Nothing really showing up in the console when I inspect either...
[image]

Comment: are you using `BrowserRouter` or `HashRouter `?

Comment: Which Router are you using? Is it BrowserRouter? Did you try having <BrowserRouter> wrapped before <Switch>?

Comment: Multiple issue, Wrapped your Switch inside BrowserRouter/HashRouter. "/" is not defined. And please check your console as well

Comment: @jain i removed the "/"  for now and ill go back to it but that really had no bearing on the issue at hand the switch is wrapped by BrowserRouter.  Thanks

Comment: @PranayTripathi I am using `BrowserRouter`

Comment: @Nimmy I am using `BrowserRouter`

Comment: Can you paste the entire file this is in so we can see how you're importing other components like `Timeline` and how you've set up this component (i.e., is it a class/functional). Also what error are you getting (paste that too)?

Also I might be nice to see how either `Timeline` or `WhatIDo` are setup as components as well.

Comment: @that_developer any console error or exception.

Comment: @CatPerry you got it.  Give me just a few to update.

Comment: This may possibly be a CSS issue.  The codebase can be found here - https://github.com/KevinDennyII/that_developer/tree/adding-react-router

Comment: You miss class container to the about main div which wraps all the about component and remove also the fade in left animation from the content for now

Comment: so a temporary fix for now is `<BrowserRouter forceRefresh={true} />` but this refreshed the entire page which we dont want...

Comment: @quirimmo thanks for answering.  how does that account for the refreshing of the page which causes everything to render appropriately?

Comment: @Jain definitely had the right idea...I completely removed "/" route and no issue so I need to set that route up the right way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the issues was not a React Router issues at all.  It was in fact a CSS issue with this specific code found in my `style.css`

```
.js .animate-box {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

when the routes are rendering their components, respectively the opacity is automatically set to 0.  Once the page is refreshed it that using the opacity as only a transition.  If I comment out the opacity, the components showed without having to refresh the page